# How can I return powershell object properties wildcard filtered by their property name?

Tags: powershell, filter, properties

I'm trying to use Get-ADUser to find a specific extended attribute of which I do not know the name. In my org, every AD user should have an attribute field that specifies whether they've been trained on a certain topic, but I don't know what that field is called exactly. So I'm hoping to search for attributes which may have specific strings in their name, such as "titleIX".

The below code doesn't work as I'm intending it to (obviously), but I hope it illustrates what I'm looking for:
 `Get-ADUser -filter 'name -like "johndoe"' -properties * | Where-Object {$_.propertyname -like "*titleIX*"}`

In this example, the hope is that the output would look something like
`trngTitleIXDone: Yes`
At that point I would know that the field is called "trngTitleIXDone" and could continue on my merry way using that for the actual reports I want to produce.

I realize I may need further piped commands to achieve the actual filtering I'm looking for, rather than just a complete list of attributes associated with an object that HAS an attribute with a name matching the query.

Thanks and please let me know if I need to explain myself better.
== Matt

P.S. Further context by request:

Q: Can't you ask your admin, or find it in ADUC?
A: The org is huge and has lots of custom attributes that are not documented (in a way I can access). Getting that information, or even finding the right person to ask would take much longer than finding it myself. And I'd like to know this skill in case this comes up again so I can avoid the delay next time.

As for ADUC, I don't know exactly the logic behind when an attribute is returned or not, but my understanding is that the attribute(s) I'm looking for have some sort of classification that prevents them from being returned unless you specifically target them by name. Simply using `properties *` does not return what I'm looking for, and the attributes listed in ADUC are more or less the same dataset.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just ask your system administrator about this or use ADUC (select "View" --> "Advanced Features) and browse through the attributes of a user?

Comment: I suggest to read this [Q&A on social.technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8da2aa4e-5ae6-47d9-ac1b-159e5e3f2612/pull-all-user-attributes-with-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) especially the answer from JohnLBevan

Comment: @Theo see my edit.

Comment: there is a hidden property on PSObjects named ... `.PSObject` & one of its properties is `.Properties`. that contains an array of the property object items with `.Name`, `.Value` and other properties. that may give you what you need.

Comment: @LotPings If I'm understanding correctly, the thread is aimed at finding attributes which might not be set, and are thus not returned. In my case, I know the attribute has a non-blank value on the objects I'm querying. As noted in my edit, I don't fully understand it but there are some attributes in my environment which are simply not returned unless you specify them by name. That does sounds like the same behavior though, and I will consider the contents of the thread you posted.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks, that sounds promising, and I'll investigate, but would you be able to provide a link or example?

Comment: @mmseng ok, I see what you mean. Perhaps [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2017/09/22/one-liner-query-the-ad-schema-for-user-object-attributes/) may prove helpful?

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the link. It does seem that I'm being slowly guided towards polling the schema. It's gross but it might have to happen.

Comment: @mmseng - i have never found any actual docs on it. [*frown*] i 1st became aware of it when a kind person helped me use it to iterate over the property names of an object when i had no idea what object i would be dealing with.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey fair enough (*shakes fist at clouds*)

Comment: @mmseng - [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry to jump in late, but I can confirm that you will have to query the schema for the custom attribute names. The `Get-ADUser` cmdlet even says in its `Get-Help` that any non-standard properties have to be specified by name, which means you have to get the name, and the schema is the place to do that. On the plus side, Theo's link shows you exactly how to do that.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Very good. Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we discovered that I was asking the wrong question for my problem, due to the arcane details of how custom AD attributes work, which I didn't fully understand. Thanks to comments by @LotPings, @Theo, and @TheMadTechnician for illuminating different possibilities.

The question, as asked, is probably most closely answered by @Lee_Dailey's comment about the hidden property of PSObjects (.PSObject), its child property (.Properties, and *its* child properties, .Name, .Value, etc.). While I don't currently have an working answer, I'm sure there's a programmatic way to use these to iterate through unknown properties of a given object.

As for my issue, I can't easily return a list of properties to iterate through for two main reasons:

1) Even when requesting all properties from a Get-AD* cmdlet (e.g. `Get-ADUser -filter 'name -like "johndoe"' -properties *`), only properties (i.e. attributes) which have a non-null (i.e. unset) value are returned. AD will never return an such attributes for a given object as they don't exist in the object. To return a list of *possible* attributes which are available in the schema, but are unused in a given object, you must (apparently) query the schema itself.

Querying the schema for possible attributes:

```
Select-Object @{n="Attributes";e={$_.maycontain + $_.systemmaycontain}} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Attributes |
Sort-Object
```

Sources:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8da2aa4e-5ae6-47d9-ac1b-159e5e3f2612/pull-all-user-attributes-with-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell (thanks to @LotPings)
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2017/09/22/one-liner-query-the-ad-schema-for-user-object-attributes/ (thanks to @Theo)

2) Apparently, even attributes which are set for an object, but are custom (i.e. not part of the default or extended set of attributes) will never be returned unless you request them by name. From the detailed help files of Get-ADUser:
`To specify an individual extended property, use the name of the property. For properties that are not default or extended properties, you must specify the LDAP display name of the attribute.`

In my case, it seems that even (at least some) org-custom attributes ARE in fact returned by requesting `-properties *`, which makes me think that, in my environment, they have somehow been specifically configured to be part of the extended set, if that's possible. If that's the case, it's possible there may be some custom attributes that haven't been configured this way, which would make it very difficult to know which schema-available attributes might be set on an object, but which need to be requested by name. To determine this I could loop through the possible attributes, requesting them all, and comparing the results to the extended set.